# Can the energy of electrochemical gradient be transformed into electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, potential-energy, electrochemistry

Imagine an impermeable wall between two aqueous solutions containing positively charged ions. If the ion concentrations differ on two sides of the wall, an electric potential energy is stored in the system. 
It can be converted into other forms of energy. For example, if a hole opens in the wall, ions will go through and the energy will dissipate into heat. In living cells an electrochemical potential can be converted into energy of chemical bonds. 
Are there any known phenomena where electrochemical gradient energy is converted into electromagnetic radiation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is what happens when you hook up a battery to a LED.

Comment: You are right. But I'm looking for a more direct route. In your example the electrochemical energy of ions is converted to voltage in the circuit (energy of electrons and holes), and then energy of electrons/holes converted to photons. Can electrochemical energy go directly to photons?

Comment: @MishaMonahov : the electrochemical energy in the battery IS the voltage in the circuit.  There's no conversion.  it's a direct transfer.

Answer (score 0):

"If electromotive force (emf) is brought to bear upon two or more dissimilar metals that are immersed in an electrolyte, creating an electrochemical reaction by electrolysis that produces energy, such as a similar process in a car battery. Therefore, can that energy be transformed into another form of energy through electromagnetic radiation and/or electric fields or magnetic fields?

If we consider that the electromotive force can either be from a device that emits electromagnetic radiation (EMR) or electric and magnetic (EM) fields, such as, EMR device being microwave oven or mobile phone or electric device vacuum cleaner or kitchen appliances? They both emit a force and comes in contact with metals that are immersed in a solution and therefore will produce $E = I \times R$.

Your thoughts would be appreciated.